# PHP or MySQL Replace for <img> tags in HTML enabled content entries

Tags: php, mysql, replace, preg-match

I’ve  tags in following format spread all over my HTML enabled content entries:

```
<img alt="" src="{assets_2100:{filedir_12}HappyDog.jpg}" style="height:400px; width:100px">
```

I need to update all these in following format either via a PHP function before displaying at frontend or just update the MySQL once and for all:

```
<img alt="" src="/uploads/HappyDog.jpg" data-assetid="2100" data-filedir="12" data-filename="HappyDog.jpg" style="height:400px; width:100px”>
```

The “*/uploads/*’ directory path is applicable for all images!

These tags were carried over when migrated content from EE

Edited: 
Okay, so far I tried the following as first step to remove the {filedir_X} from address:

```
    $parse_encoded = true;
    $pattern = ($parse_encoded)
        ? '/(?:{|&#123;)filedir_(\d+)(?:}|&#125;)/'
        : '/{filedir_(\d+)}/';
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlcontent, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
    {
        foreach ($matches as $match){
            $htmlcontent = str_replace($match[0], '', $htmlcontent);
        }
    }
```

Then modified this to remove “{asset”, but ending up with “}” at the “src”  attribute!

Comment: what format is this anyway ?

Comment: @MarkoPaju This format was applicable on Expression Engine, but at this point I just need to reserve all attribute for later JS manipulation before removing them from “src” attribute!

Comment: In my opinion it's better to understand the regular expressions, however a working example could help in getting to understand it. Not convinced it's the best approach but take a look on [txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3?s={assets_2100:{filedir_12}HappyDog.jpg}&3).

Comment: Maybe you could start with this https://3v4l.org/2KMsU

Comment: Since this is because of a migration I think it's best to update the data in MySQL once and for all. This could even be done offline in a texteditor or whatever and then put back online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching matches with `preg_match_all` to loop over results and to use `str_replace` is a waste of time. PHP has two functions for regex string replacements: `preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback` (respectively for simple and complex replacements).

```
if ( $parseEncoded )
    $htmlContent = strtr($htmlContent, ['&#123;' => '{', '&#125;' => '}']);

$pattern = '~src=\K(["\']?){assets_(\d+):{filedir_(\d+)}([^}]+)}\1~i';
$replacement = '"/uploads/$4" data-assetid="$2" data-filedir="$3" data-filename="$4"';

$htmlContent = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $htmlContent);
```

Note that I changed the variable names: you have to choose between camelCase, snake_case and lowercase.

Comment: Short, elegant and beautiful. Works like a charm. Thank you!